# WPF IsEnabled Binding to Property in Collection, which Depends on other Property in another Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Solution link: https://github.com/fallingsappy/portfolio/tree/master/DDrop

Hi, everyone! I have a problem with IsEnabled binding of TabItem. It kinda hard to explain, but I try. I have a collection called User. User contains UserSeries collection of Series class. UserSeries have another collection called DropPhotosSeries. Also UserSeries have property called:

```
private bool _canDrawPlot;
public bool CanDrawPlot
{
    get
    {
        return _dropPhotosSeries?.Where(x => x.Drop.RadiusInMeters != null).ToList().Count > 1 && _dropPhotosSeries?.Where(x => x.Drop.RadiusInMeters == null).ToList().Count == 0;
    }
    set
    {
        _canDrawPlot = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CanDrawPlot"));
    }
}
```

Based on this property. TabItem should be enabled or disabled. But this TabItem doesn't seems to notice changes of the property. I've tried many approaches, but still nothing. Here some XAML:

```
    <TabItem IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=AppMainWindow, Path=User.IsAnySelectedSeriesCantDrawPlot}" Name="CombinedSeriesPlot" Header="Общий график серий">
        <uc:ScatterPlot User="{Binding User, ElementName=AppMainWindow, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </TabItem>
```

Some of the codebehind:

```
public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Series> _userSeries;
    public ObservableCollection<Series> UserSeries
    {
        get
        {
            return _userSeries;
        }
        set
        {
            _userSeries = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("UserSeries"));
        }
    }

    private bool _isAnySelectedSeriesCantDrawPlot;
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsAnySelectedSeriesCantDrawPlot
    {
        get
        {
            return _userSeries?.Where(x => x?.CanDrawPlot == false).ToList().Count > 0;
        }
        set
        {
            _isAnySelectedSeriesCantDrawPlot = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsAnySelectedSeriesCantDrawPlot"));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

I've tried to create dependent property in UserClass, but i think property in UserSeries should be enough somehow:

```
public class Series : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<DropPhoto> _dropPhotosSeries;
    public ObservableCollection<DropPhoto> DropPhotosSeries
    {
        get
        {
            return _dropPhotosSeries;
        }
        set
        {
            _dropPhotosSeries = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DropPhotosSeries"));
        }
    }

    private bool _canDrawPlot;
    public bool CanDrawPlot
    {
        get
        {
            return _dropPhotosSeries?.Where(x => x.Drop.RadiusInMeters != null).ToList().Count > 1 && _dropPhotosSeries?.Where(x => x.Drop.RadiusInMeters == null).ToList().Count == 0;
        }
        set
        {
            _canDrawPlot = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CanDrawPlot"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

Maybe DropPhoto should throw some event, that CanDrowProperty need to update itself and update TabItem? I really don't know. But here is DropPhoto class:

```
public class DropPhoto : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Drop _drop;
    public Drop Drop
    {
        get
        {
            return _drop;
        }
        set
        {
            _drop = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Drop"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

It's contains Drop class, which has RadiusInMeters property:

```
public class Drop : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double? _radiusInMeters;
    public double? RadiusInMeters
    {
        get
        {
            return _radiusInMeters;
        }
        set
        {
            _radiusInMeters = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RadiusInMeters"));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

For full solution. Please check github link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to find out what exactly wrong in your code but I'll try to answer directly to the question with simple example code

```cs
public class FirstClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    SecondClass secondClass = new SecondClass();

    private bool _firstProperty;
    public bool FirstProperty
    {
        get => _firstProperty;
        set
        {
            _firstProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FirstProperty));
        }
    }

    private void SecondClass_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(secondClass.SecondProperty)) FirstProperty = secondClass.SecondProperty;
    }

    public FirstClass()
    {
        secondClass.PropertyChanged += SecondClass_PropertyChanged;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
public class SecondClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _secondProperty;
    public bool SecondProperty
    {
        get => _secondProperty;
        set
        {
            _secondProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SecondProperty));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

In this example any change of `SecondProperty` will cause change of the `FirstProperty`.